# React - what is different by including all the code of a component in the parent vs. not

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand and use [this react mapkit repo](https://github.com/chrisdrackett/react-mapkit).

What I'm trying to understand is what is the difference between these two examples. You'll see that I just move the Component `UseMapExample` into the parent `Home`.

I'm curious what is happening with React and the custom hook. useMap acts differently in the two examples (it works in the first, in the second, it doesn't work - no errors - but all the variables remained undefined).

The code for the provider and useMap are [here](https://github.com/chrisdrackett/react-mapkit/tree/master/src) and at the bottom with the imports to know which file to look at.

Before (works):

```
const UseMapExample = () => {
  const { map, mapProps } = useMap();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="myMap">
        <Map {...mapProps} />
      </div>
      <style jsx>{`
        .myMap {
          height: 700px;
        }
      `}</style>
    </>
  );
};

const Home: FunctionComponent<MapProps> = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MapkitProvider tokenOrCallback={mapkitKey}>
        <UseMapExample />
      </MapkitProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

and just doing it all in one functional component. After (Doesn't work):

```
const Home: FunctionComponent<MapProps> = () => {
  const { map, mapProps } = useMap();

  return (
    <>
      <MapkitProvider tokenOrCallback={mapkitKey}>
        <div className="myMap">
          <Map {...mapProps} />
        </div>
        <style jsx>{`
          .myMap {
            height: 700px;
          }
        `}</style>
      </MapkitProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

I think it has to do with where `useMap` is running, but I want to understand the react *why* on what is happening here.

For the code for any of the imported modules they are [here](https://github.com/chrisdrackett/react-mapkit/tree/master/src).

Imports are:

```
import { Map } from "../components/mapkit/Map";
import { useMap } from "../components/mapkit/useMap";
import { MapkitProvider } from "../components/mapkit/MapkitProvider";
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, the first one just doesn't render the map. The useMap doesn't work the same in the two examples.

Comment: Probably you need to use the `useMap` hook in a child of `MapkitProvider`?

Comment: Share the code for `MapkitProvider` and `useMap`

Comment: Thanks for the help, a GitHub link to it is posted at the bottom - and here: https://github.com/chrisdrackett/react-mapkit/tree/master/src and yes I think it does need to be a child, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: It's because it's using React Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). `MapkitProvider` provides the context to its children